# Comparing two complex arrays not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, angular

thanks for checking out my question! I am currently developing a website using angular 9 and expressjs, which I am new to, and am running into an issue with the user api and the website.

**QUESTION:**

I am to compare a permission array from the API with an array on the angular website and return true if an array item is in the other array. However, for some reason comparing isn't working properly, it seems to return true as long as the array item has the text "role" in it, and its not actually comparing "developer" to "developer" (see below examples of the arrays).

**API Role Array:**

```
[
  {
    role: "user"
  },
  {
    role: "developer"
  }
]
```

**Role Array on Website:**

```
[
  {
    role: "moderator"
  },
  {
    role: "administrator"
  },
  {
    role: "developer"
  }
]
```

I have tried using anything I could read about online, but perhaps I am overlooking something here. Do I need to get rid of the "role" tags and then compare? I couldn't find a way to really do this.

Thanks to anyone who replies, it really means a lot to me <3

**ANSWER:** Thanks to @mateleco I created an angular function from his solution.

```js
checkRoles (webRoles, apiRoles) {
    const result = webRoles.some((obj1) => {
      return apiRoles.some((obj2) => {
        return obj1.role == obj2.role;
      });
    });
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does your comparison code look like?

Comment: How do you currently compare these arrays? Also, are you currently learning AngularJS (Angular 1)? In 2020?

Comment: Well I have tried many ways to compare, using `.some()` and `.filter()`. Comparing the two arrays wasn't working at all, so now I am trying to put the arrays together, and then return true if a duplicate was found. (this obviously can't be the most efficient way)

Comment: @JeremyThille I am using angular 9 haha

Comment: Ah, because you said that you are `using angularjs` which is Angular 1

Comment: Sorry for the mixup my mistake, I edited my question and changed it to Angular 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var apiRoleArr = [
  {
    role: "user"
  },
  {
    role: "developer"
  }
];

var websiteRoleArr = [
  {
    role: "moderator"
  },
  {
    role: "administrator"
  },
  {
    role: "developer"
  }
];

var result = websiteRoleArr.some(function(obj1){
  return apiRoleArr.some(function(obj2){
    return obj1.role == obj2.role;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

This checks whether there is a role that is both in apiRoleArr and in websiteRoleArr. I don't know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Let me go implement it and try it out :)

Comment: Oops! I have a typo: it's "==", not "=".

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
const api = [....]; // array of api
const app = [....]; // array of client app

const answer = api.reduce(
    (a, b) => (a || app.findIndex(item => item.role === b.role) >= 0),
    false);

console.log(answer);
```